# Moving all files in a folder to another folder without moving the subfolders

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a folder named `folder1`. It has a bunch of files and two subfolders `subfolder1` and `subfolder2`. I want to move all the files in `folder1` to `subfolder2` except the `subfolder1`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` and `mv`:

Here's my folder setup:

```
$ find folder1
folder1
folder1/subfolder2
folder1/subfolder2/i
folder1/subfolder2/h
folder1/subfolder2/g
folder1/subfolder1
folder1/subfolder1/f
folder1/subfolder1/e
folder1/subfolder1/d
folder1/c
folder1/b
folder1/a
```

To model your case, I want to move `a`, `b`, and `c` to `subfolder2`:

```
$ find folder1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv "{}" folder1/subfolder2 \;
```

Now if I look at the content of `folder1`:

```
$ find folder1
folder1
folder1/subfolder2
folder1/subfolder2/a
folder1/subfolder2/b
folder1/subfolder2/c
folder1/subfolder2/i
folder1/subfolder2/h
folder1/subfolder2/g
folder1/subfolder1
folder1/subfolder1/f
folder1/subfolder1/e
folder1/subfolder1/d
```

Answer (score 1):

To move the non-directory files in `folder1` (hidden ones excluded) to `folder1/subfolder2`, in the `zsh` shell, you'd do:

```
mv folder1/*(^/) folder1/subfolder2/
```

To move all files regardless of their type except `subfolder1` (and obviously `subfolder2` as well):

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
mv folder1/^(subfolder1|subfolder2) folder1/subfolder2
```

To also move hidden files, add the `D` glob qualifier.

Answer (score -1):

Use `find` and `xargs`. Read `man find xargs`. Since you didn't say what the filenames look like (embedded spaces, other funny characters ), I'll use `-print0`.

```
find folder1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r mv --target-directory=subfolder2
```

Comment: The target directory should be `folder1/subfolder2`, I reckon?